# Snowflake : Calculate number of calendar days

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 date fields and would like to write a condition
want to see the results if date2 field is >45 calendar days from date1 field

I tried `dateadd` and extract but not getting the results i want. Can you help me out.

```
Date1           Date2                                                                      
2020-01-02      2020-04-01
2020-02-01      2020-03-09
2021-01-04      2021-04-09
```

Would like to see if Date2 is >45 calendar days from date1

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT date1,
    date2,
    datediff('days', date1, date2) as diff,
    abs(diff)>45 as filter
FROM (VALUES                                                                    
      ('2020-01-02'::date, '2020-04-01'::date),
      ('2020-02-01'::date, '2020-03-09'::date),
      ('2021-01-04'::date, '2021-04-09'::date)
      v(date1, date2)
 )
 --WHERE filter
 ;
```

gives:

```
DATE1       DATE2       DIFF    FILTER
2020-01-02  2020-04-01  90      TRUE
2020-02-01  2020-03-09  37      FALSE
2021-01-04  2021-04-09  95      TRUE
```

so you would expect to only get two rows if you use this logic in the filter, which is what happens.

```
SELECT date1,
    date2
FROM (VALUES                                                                    
      ('2020-01-02'::date, '2020-04-01'::date),
      ('2020-02-01'::date, '2020-03-09'::date),
      ('2021-01-04'::date, '2021-04-09'::date)
      v(date1, date2)
 )
 WHERE abs(datediff('days', date1, date2)) > 45
 ;
```

gives:

```
DATE1       DATE2
2020-01-02  2020-04-01
2021-01-04  2021-04-09
```

Now I used ABS because the difference can be in ether direction, where if you only want row where date2 is greater than 45 after date1 then the ABS can be dropped.

Comment: Thank you. This is working. I removed ABS for my logic.

Comment: @deeps you are welcome, remember to press the tick mark next to the answer the solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
WHERE date1 + INTERVAL '45 day' < date2;
```

Not SARGable version:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, date1, date2) > 45;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7e257595cc44325f245fb8abb2b89977)**

Comment: This is not retuning the records greater than 45 calendar days

Comment: @deeps I have added an example